# Gallery type scroll view in android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to implement a scroller like show in the image below.
[image]

I have tried using viewpager but it only shows one item at a time. And I need to show 5 of them and of different sizes. The one in middle needs to be bigger.

Each Item is a frameLayout that contains an ImageView and a TexView, I dont have any problem implementing that part. The problem is it needs to be a scroller and have many items in scroller e.g upto 15 maybe. But should have only 5 items visible at any one time just like shown below. I have tried many implementations. Please some one give me a working example as I have already tried many examples none of them works perfectly. I have waisted more than a week on this one.

Comment: The middle image needs to be zoomedIn and keep the sides bit smaller as shown in picture above.

Comment: please post your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control it by overriding getPageWidth() in the PagerFragmentAdapter:

```
@Override 
public float getPageWidth(int position) { 
    return(0.4f); 
}
```

and making sure the size of your images is not too large, so that the page width fits multiple images.

[image]


Here are all the steps to set this up:

1) Add a fragment container to your activity layout, where you will load the PhotoPagerFragment:

```
<!-- PHOTO PAGER FRAGMENT -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/photoPagerFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:tag="sticky" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
</FrameLayout>
```

2) Inject the PhotoPagerFragment in your activity's `onCreate()`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        //Insert the fragment
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.photoPagerFragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new PhotoPagerFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.photoPagerFragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }
```

3) Create a layout for your PhotoPagerFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/photoPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

4) Create your PhotoPagerFragment:

```
public class PhotoPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager       mPhotoPager;
    private PagerAdapter    mPhotoAdapter;

    public static final String TAG = "PhotoPagerFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_pager, container, false);

        mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoPagerFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPhotoPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.photoPager);
        mPhotoPager.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

5) And the adapter:

```
public class PhotoPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int[] Images = new int[] { 
            R.drawable.photo_1, R.drawable.photo_2,
            R.drawable.photo_3, R.drawable.photo_4,
            R.drawable.photo_5, R.drawable.photo_6
    };

    private int mCount = Images.length;


    public PhotoPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PhotoDetailsFragment.newInstance(Images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override 
    public float getPageWidth(int position) { 
        return(0.4f); 
    } 

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

6) And finally, your PhotoDetailsFragment that will show each image:

```
public final class PhotoDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private int photoResId;

    private static final String TAG = "PhotoDetailsFragment";
    public  static final String EXTRA_PHOTO_ID = "com.sample.photo_res_id";


    public static PhotoDetailsFragment newInstance(int photoResId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_PHOTO_ID, photoResId);

        PhotoDetailsFragment fragment = new PhotoDetailsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        photoResId = (Integer)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_PHOTO_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        image.setImageResource(photoResId);

        // Hook up the clicks on the thumbnail views
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
            }
        });

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-1, -1));

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(image);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try your code, still it doesn't answer how to zoom the centre focused element and make other elements considerably smaller as shown in picture above. though I have some ideas on how to achieve that I'll let you know if I have any problem.

Comment: Using the above code I am able to make the scroller, but can't get the item to align perfectly in middle.

Comment: To get the right sizes, you can adjust the size of the image based on which visible position it occupies in the view pager. I would also use a fade-in animation for each photo. As for alignment, they should be center-aligned if you're setting layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) for your PhotoDetailsFragment. It worked for me. Perhaps, check your parent layout to make sure it's not imposing any other layout constraints on the photos